# How to scale Factors and Position for Blend

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I'm stuck at this problem for few hours but can't seem to make progress.

I have a perfect annulus (Fig 1), but when I increase the inner ellipse, I'm loosing the drawing (Fig 2)

[image]

I guess that I need to scale Blend.Factor and/or Blend.Positions, but I don't know hoy to do it.

This is my Factor and Position arrays:

```
_Factors = new float[] { 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f };
_Positions = new float[] { 0f, 0.25f, 0.5f, 1f };
```

And this is my Paint function:

```
   using (Brush oInnerBrush = new SolidBrush(_InnerColor))
     {
        using (Pen oBaseBrush = new Pen(_BaseColor, 2))
        {
           using (GraphicsPath oGraphPath = new GraphicsPath())
           {
              // Outside
              oGraphPath.AddEllipse(oRect);

              // Inside
              oGraphPath.AddEllipse(oRect.Shrink(_InnerWidth));

              using (PathGradientBrush oGradBrush = new PathGradientBrush(oGraphPath))
              {
                 Blend oBlend = new Blend();
                 oBlend.Factors = _Factors;
                 oBlend.Positions = _Positions;
                 oGradBrush.Blend = oBlend;

                 oGradBrush.CenterColor = ((SolidBrush)oInnerBrush).Color;
                 oGradBrush.SurroundColors = new Color[] { oBaseBrush.Color };

                 Area.FillPath(oGradBrush, oGraphPath);
              }
           }
        }
      }
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

EDIT: I'm using the code in [this question by BlueMonkMN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716984/how-do-i-draw-an-annulus-doughnut-using-gdi)